# Prove $(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2 \ge \frac{c^2(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}+\frac{b^2(1-a^2)(1-c^2)}{(ac+b)^2}+\frac{a^2(1-c^2)(1-b^2)}{(bc+a)^2}$

Tags: inequality

Note: we have $a>0,b>0,c>0$.

Solve $(1-a)^2+(1-b)^2+(1-c)^2 \ge \frac{c^2(1-a^2)(1-b^2)}{(ab+c)^2}+\frac{b^2(1-a^2)(1-c^2)}{(ac+b)^2}+\frac{a^2(1-c^2)(1-b^2)}{(bc+a)^2}$ where $a>0,b>0,c>0$. Elementary (high-school) methods are preferred.

I'm not an expert in inequalities. I only know GM-AM and it does not appear to be working. It is not clear to me how to take advantage of the symmetry here.

Comment: @dezdichado this is proved in the answer below for $a,b,c\ge 0$

Comment: @dezdichado how come? I see it may not hold if the assumption $a,b,c\ge 0$ is not given. Otherwise, it looks fine.

Comment: @dezdichado I double checked. This inequality should be true and we have additional condition that $a,b,c>0$.

Comment: Some years ago, I saw this problem. In a blog entry posted in 2013, it was said that this problem was proposed by Dongyi Wei (full marks both at 50th IMO 2009 and 49th IMO 2008) and was solved by Zipei Nie (full marks at 51st IMO 2010). Nie's proof is ugly. Some years ago, I also gave a ugly (long) proof.

Comment: @RiverLi so the proof in the linked question is legit?

Comment: @dezdichado  I don't know. I have not yet looked at that proof.